Is there a way to consolidate multiple functions with event listeners?
I'm trying to streamline my code and running into a brick wall. In the actual project, I have ten radio inputs that appear on a button click. What I want is that when a radio option is selected, all radios disappear and the checked option becomes the background image.
This has allowed me to do that:
optionOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionOneImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
   }
});

However, since there are 10 options, is there some type of switch statement that I could write that would read what was clicked and collapse the radio options? I have to implement something similar for something with over 40 radio options, so I want to make this as concise as possible.
Here's a CodePen for the full working code as I have it.


const showButton = document.getElementById("option-button");
const optionsGrid = document.getElementById("option-grid");
const optionRadios = document.getElementsByClassName("option-radio");
const optionOne = document.getElementById("1");
const optionTwo = document.getElementById("2");
const optionThree = document.getElementById("3");
const optionFour = document.getElementById("4");
const optionOneImage = document.getElementById("option-1-image").src;
const optionTwoImage = document.getElementById("option-2-image").src;
const optionThreeImage = document.getElementById("option-3-image").src;
const optionFourImage = document.getElementById("option-4-image").src;

showButton.addEventListener("click", showOptions);

function showOptions() {
  let array = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    array.push(optionRadios[i].classList.value);
  }

  if (array.includes("option-radio hide")) {
    optionsGrid.style.animation = "open-animation 100ms linear 1";
    optionsGrid.style.display = "grid";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
      optionRadios[i].classList.replace("hide", "active");
    }
  } else {
    optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
      optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
    }
  }
}

optionOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionOneImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";

  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
  }
});

optionTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionTwoImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";

  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
  }
});

optionThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionThreeImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";

  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
  }
});

optionFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionFourImage}")`;
  showButton.innerHTML = "";

  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
  }
});
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

#option-button {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

#option-grid {
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 1250px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes open-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<fieldset id="console-select">
  <legend>Radio Option</legend>
  <button type="button" id="option-button">Select</button>
  <div id="option-grid">
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="1">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="1" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x200" id="option-1-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="2">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="2" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x199" id="option-2-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="3">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" id="3" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x198" id="option-3-image">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option-radio hide">
      <label for="4">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="4" id="4" hidden>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x197" id="option-4-image">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>




You can add a class to all the radios (or also query only radio elements) and then do a loop to add the event listener to all the elements.
For example:
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="1" hidden>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="2" hidden>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" id="3" hidden>
</form>

const allRadios = document.querySelectorAll("form input[type='radio']") //gets all input type radio inside form
allRadios.forEach((singleRadioElement)=>{ // loops over all the elements
  singleRadioElement.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ // adds the event listener for each element
    showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${optionOneImage}")`;
    showButton.innerHTML = "";
  
    optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
    for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
      optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
    }
  })
})


You can add the eventListener to the form instead of to each individual radio button. Then listen for the change event to know a radio button was selected.
You can use the event object to know which radio button was selected.
If you want you can still use a for loop to hide each button individually, or you could hide the whole form.


let form = document.querySelector("form")
let btns = document.querySelector("input[name=selectback]")


form.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    console.log("you clicked on: " + event.target.value)
  
    for(let btn of btns){
      btn.classList.replace("active", "hide")
    }
})
<form>

<input type="radio" id="back1" name="selectback" value="back1">
<label for="back1">background 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="back2" name="selectback" value="back2">
<label for="back2">background 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="back3" name="selectback" value="back3">
<label for="back3">background 3</label><br>

</form>




You can address elements/json objects dynamically in JS like this:


for(let i = 1; i < numOptions; i++) {
  var currVariable = eval("option" + i);
  currVariable.addEventListener("click", ...
}



It's much easier if you use this notation "option1", "option2" instead of "one", "two", "three".

Event bubbling is what you're looking for
const urlToIdMap = {
  1: "https://placehold.co/600x200",
  2: "https://placehold.co/600x199",
  3: "https://placehold.co/600x198",
  4: "https://placehold.co/600x197"
};

optionsGrid.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const idBubbledUp = event.target.id;
  switch (idBubbledUp) {
    case "1": {
      showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${urlToIdMap[idBubbledUp]}")`;
      break;
    }
    case "2": {
      showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${urlToIdMap[idBubbledUp]}")`;
      break;
    }
    case "3": {
      showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${urlToIdMap[idBubbledUp]}")`;
      break;
    }
    case "4": {
      showButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${urlToIdMap[idBubbledUp]}")`;
      break;
    }
  }
  hideRadioGrid();
});

function hideRadioGrid() {
  showButton.innerHTML = "";
  optionsGrid.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < optionRadios.length; i++) {
    optionRadios[i].classList.replace("active", "hide");
  }
}

CodePen
